# How to calculate the external quantum efficiency of an LED?

Tags: light-emitting-diodes

I am currently starting to work on LED but I am confused how can I calculate the external quantum efficiency for my LED? like I know the basic idea, I want to know what experimental setup should  I used for my LED and how? In my Lab we have Raman spectrometer with CCD detector.